# font blurry in IE10 on navigation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have crated MENU Navigation with fixed and scroller, when scrolled up and fixedTop menu navigation after that text will appear littla blurry or strech in IE10 compare to other browers.https://i.stack.imgur.com/NELyS.jpg

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NELyS.jpg)

Pleasee see attached orignal and blurry output

Comment: Please post your code and output.

Comment: i have only issue on IE10 browser, that one also only required, please help me out. otherwise all fine in coding.

Comment: You didn't attach the images.

Comment: sorry manoj, now you can see the attachment.

Comment: @ManojKumar can u please find attachment, please provide solution ASAP, i need this Soon, please help me out.

Comment: What about the code you are using?

Comment: @ManojKumar Im using bootsrap code. <nav class="navbar navbar-default affix-top"> when home page open that time above code is rendering and once navigation top fixed that time <nav class="navbar navbar-default affix">